# Как сделать фон, заполняющий всё пространство? CSS

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть фотография. Как её кинуть на фон, чтобы она заполонила всё пространство, но при этом сохранились пропорции?
Спасибо.

Comment: размеры фото какие?

Comment: без разницы

Comment: да потише ты... 
какая разница какое фото? Может я захочу поставить 1256px на 2000px 
или 500 на 500.
Да и решение я нашёл.. при помощи CSS3

Comment: @Palmervan, про потише - хороший совет. Плохое настроение - не повод превращать форум программистов в бутовский подъезд.

Алсо, размер для вопроса реально не важен.

Comment: Было похожее задание не так давно, по ТЗ было сказано что большая картинка должна центрироваться, если размеры экрана меньше размеров картинки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При увеличении размера картинка с маленьким разрешением будет терять качество. Все зависит только он ее качества и размеров, до которых ты хочешь ее увеличить. Из-за такой "не универсальности" масштабирования принято делать сайты со статическими рамками, что бы одинаково-хорошо смотрелось на широкоформатных экранах

Comment: Я решил эту проблему при помощи CSS3

`-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-khtml-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;`

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать сделать набор картинок под популярные разрешения и вставлять ближайшую javascript'ом. Вообще в самой идее мало хорошего, но если надо - надо решать)

```
<body id="body">
<script type="text/javascript">
var swidth = [
  1024,
  1280,
  1600,
  1920
];
var imgw = 2560; // по дефолту самое большое
for (var sw in swidth)
  if (screen.width <= swidth[sw]) { // подбираем такое же или большее разрешение
  imgw = swidth[sw];
  break;
  }
document.getElementById('body').style.background = "#fff url('/images/"+imgw+".jpg') 50% 50% no-repeat"; // ставим фон
</script>
```

Примерно так... Писал здесь, проверка-правка на вас)

Comment: Да, еще это можно решить через такую же подгрузку изображения, только чтобы она ресайзилась на сервере с помощью, например, php+gd и выдавалась в браузер, с кэшированием и прочей оптимизацией, но это вариант с очень грустным качеством картинки, да и времени у меня не особо для таких дел)